# Make fill-paragraph in *raw* python docstring leave the triple-quotes on separate line

Tags: python, fill-paragraph

This is almost the same question as [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/make-fill-paragraph-in-python-docstring-leave-the-triple-quotes-on-separate-line), but not quite. I happen to like the docstring style

```
def f():
    """
    docstring

    another line
    """
```

so in emacs I have `python-fill-docstring-style` set to `(quote django)`. Works great. But it doesn't work with this:

```
def f2():
    r"""
    A raw docstring with \n and \t and other symbols in it.

    Another line.
    """
```

If I run `fill-paragraph` on the first paragraph of this docstring, it turns it into:

```
r""" A raw docstring with \n and \t and other symbols in it.
```

If I run it on the second paragraph, it becomes

```
Another line.  """
```

Is this a bug or is there a customization setting I'm overlooking? The same problem arises if the docstring starts with `b"""` or `u"""`.

Comment: This was reported as a bug, and it seems to have been fixed in Emacs 25.